# How to do take! in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

What is a good way to take (keep) the first n elements in an array and delete the rest?

If there is no built-in method, then

```
def take! ary, n
  ...
end

z = (1..10).to_a
take! z, 5
# z is [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use `Array#slice!`

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x.slice!(2..-1) # Will take! the first 2 elements of the array
x # => [1, 2]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Am getting `x #=> [3, 4]`. Not sure why?

Comment: Haha. That's correct. @sagarpandya82. I came up with this same solution and it didn't work. It appears to work because it returns `[1,2]`.

Comment: @ChrisHeald - Besides you and me, Jörg W Mittag thought the same. Is there a special reason that it would seem to work that way?

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities.

The Swiss Army Knife that *always* works is [`Array#replace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-replace) which simply replaces the contents of the receiver with the contents of the argument, and thus can be used to transform any array into any other array, so you can just say something like:

```
class Array
  def take!(n)
    replace(take(n))
  end
end
```

Using [`Array#slice!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) is another possibility:

```
class Array
  def take!(n)
    slice!(0, n)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def taker(arr, n)
  arr.pop(arr.length - n)
  arr
end

p taker([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) #=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: The idea is to modify the array. `take` will is the same as taker.

Comment: @BSeven. Okay changed my answer, not sure if it's any better.

Comment: Yes, that works. I upvoted your answer. `z = (1..5).to_a; taker z, 2; z`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array#replace` suggests itself:

```
z = (1..10).to_a
z.object_id    # 23576880

def z.take! n
  replace(take n)
end

z.take! 5      # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
z.object_id    # 23576880
```

Example defines singleton method, but you may define `#take!` on your array-derived class, using refinement on a module etc.